# Working with Disconnected Entities, Following "Database first" approach

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, sql-server-2012-express

I'm studying Entity Framework since I'm developing WPF Applications that will be deployed over a LAN, Database in a server and applications in the other machines.

I heard about disconnected entities and I think that's what I need.

One of my problems is that a book that I'm reading develops the idea around the code first approach, but I want to use the database first approach since we want to design the database in sql server, along with stored procedures and triggers, and then use the Entity Data Model wizard to generate the dbcontext.

We don't want to modify the model generated by the wizard, where can I find easy documentation about this topic?

Thanks in advance

Rafael

Comment: Disconnected entities just mean they're not being tracked by the change tracker of the Dbcontext.  Depending on how you are building application it really wouldn't use disconnected entities like you would run into in a web application.

Comment: Then I guess that I have to build some WCF Data Service, right?, Where can I find a good introduction on building such a service, using DBContext from EF 4.x, and following the Database first approach with SQL Server? ------- How am I building those apps?, with VS2012, EF 4.x, Database first, MVVM, WPF

Comment: Is there any reason you can't just have the `DbContext` belong to the application rather than creating a service for it?  Do you plan on having this consumed from multiple clients (Desktop & Web)?